# RavenDB progmatically empty database

Tags: ravendb

Is there a command in RavenDB that empties everything in a store? Something like Store.Empty?

Comment: No. Why would you want to do this?  There is probably a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and there wouldn't be one.
That would *assure* accidental data loss.

You probably want to run in memory for tests, right? We have explicit support for that.

Comment: Yes it is for testing(gallio unit test) , what I am doing now is that I am creating a new store for each test (for every [TestFixture]). That seems to be working. Is that the recommended way?

Comment: Yes.  For every test, you should use a new embedded in-memory store.  Be sure to put the store in a using statement so it disposes cleanly.  See also [RavenDB.Tests.Helpers](http://nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Tests.Helpers/2.0.2177-Unstable) if you are on 2.0.